# Is Redis an appropriate message system for a corporate alert messaging system?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, redis, stackexchange.redis

I've been asked to create a simple alert messaging system for my organization.  I've been looking into Redis and I'm wondering if I should build the app with that as the communication engine.

My requirements are:

- Alert composer must be web based
- Alert messages must be able to be sent to all computers on the network or any subset of computers
- Computer client must acknowledge back to the system that it received the message
- Servers must be clusterable across datacenters.
- Messages must be delivered quickly to clients
- Must run on Windows Stack

I'm thinking about setting up a web farm with an asp.net page for the composer, and SQL Server as the data repository.  I was planning on having a series of WCF endpoints on the farm as well, to handle inter-server communication and server-client communication.

The inter-server communication would be for things like coordinating and distributing the list of clients to receive an alert, where as the server-client communication would be for getting the actual alert to the client computers.

The more I've thought about that approach, the more I realize how many moving parts that requires. (Heartbeats sent from each client to the servers, heartbeats from all of the servers sent to each other...)

Since reading about Redis, I'm wondering if I can remove the WCF endpoints and use Redis's Pub-Sub capabilities to handle message distribution?  Does Redis distribute publishing events across all the nodes in the cluster?  Can I have all of my client applications directly subscribe to the Redis database and will those connections be balanced on the cluster?

Comment: Why the down vote? I thought this was a pretty on topic question?  I guess some people just can't embrace anything that's not SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis cluster is still young and not a big strength for Redis. It is mainly for sharding data between redis nodes. Redis sentinel is mainly for managing a master (for writes) and many slaves (for reads). Balancing the load between clients should be manual AFAIK.
 The partition tolerance for redis is actually bad (but it is pretty good for the rest).

Do you need reliable delivery? Do you need re-sending of messages? Redis won't do that, if you are not subscribed, then you won't receive the message and no help to check which messages were already sent (or you implement your own system with Entreprise Integration Patterns on redis). Also redis is not durable, a crash can cause data loss.

For publish subscribe on a cluster I suggest you take a look at apache Kafka which is quite popular with cluster technologies especially for big data.

http://kafka.apache.org

Comment: Kafka looks very interesting.  Thank you for the heads up!  You've given me a lot to think about